# How to use S3 with aws lambda to send and retrieve text file data

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So I'm completely new to lambda and S3 and I need to be able to let a client send and retrieve image uri data from S3

Anyone know where I should start?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your clients , send and retrieve images and metadata about the images to s3 , you don't even lambda to do so , you can use any of AWS sdk's available for a variety of programming languages to directly interact with s3.

for e.g, I am attaching a link to example to make a photo gallery type application using s3 and javascript sdk for AWS. you can do such with any programming language for whch sdk are available

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Answer (score 0):

Your client can directly interact with AWS S3 using AWS SDK for javascript, using this client can directly upload and retrieve data from the browser.

If you are planning to use S3 with lambda. Attach API Gateway endpoint to AWS Lambda, using this endpoint your client can make REST calls to your Lambda.
Write a Lambda function to handle GET and POST request to retrieve and send data. One Lambda function can have only one entry point, keep this in mind while writing code.

Use this lambda function to connect to S3. As you are new, keep in mind to give Lambda role permission to access S3.